# Can 'AI' be used as a noun object?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

For example is saying "He created an AI that can play video games for him" correct? by saying this I mean that this guy created a program/machine powered by artifical intelligence that can play his video game.
A simillar sentence appears in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIQBsfuMTjQ)  video starting from second 38.

Another example I found through a quick search is "Microsoft's AI can detect your emotions"

Comment: Yes, the noun phrase "an AI that can play video games for him" is object of "created". Your second example is different. Here, the noun phrase "Microsoft's AI" is the subject of the sentence, and "your emotions" is object of "detect".

Comment: That was helpful, thank you.